# Windows update killed my internet connection

Tags: windows, internet, windows-update, internet-connection

Im having major problems with a new windows update. On the latests update, my internet connection becomes broken. This is very abstract. The only way that I can fix it is to obviously do a system restore to before the update.

Ive ran McAfee, Bitdefender, Spybot, Ad-aware and Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware... it came all clean (just a few tracking cookie files).

I have as well done system restore and disabled Windows Update, but it STILL kills my connection on reboot.

This is getting increasingly frustrating, as I have no idea what I can do anymore. Making a system restore everytime I want to go online is not healthy. If there is a kind soul out there that could give me some pointers, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Im running Vista.

Comment: See this question - http://superuser.com/questions/164742/windows-update-destroys-my-internet-connection/164744

Comment: ChrisF, that did not solve anything Im afraid. There are no previous restore points. And ive disabled any updates from happening, but reboot still kills my connection!

Comment: What's getting installed when you run Windows Update? It may be a problem with incompatible drivers.

Comment: Nothing in particular, it has an outlook update and a microsoft windows malicious software removal tool update.

Comment: What happens if you install only one of the updates? I seriously doubt that either could be the cause of the issue, but this might narrow it down a little.

Answer (score 1):

Go to command prompt and run the following command:

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Reboot after and hopefully that will correct things.

Comment: I tried that yesterday actually. It didnt help unfortunately. Any other ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have any network connectivity?  If not, it could be a fluke, and you networking card may be faulty.

Comment: Yes the network connectivity is fine. My networking card is completely fine. Any other ideas?

Comment: Wireless or wired?  Also, is this your router?  If so, can you connect with another computer.  What protocols are you using - WEP WPA WPA2...

Answer (score 0):

Try booting in Safe mode.

If the problem doesn't occur, then it is actually an installed application or third-party driver that is killing the Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Control Panel, click on Network Connections.
2. Try and disable your network connection. It probably won't disable, but do this step anyway.
3. Reboot your computer in safe mode without networking
4. Once your computer reboots, open command prompt (Start → Run → `cmd`)
5. Type `net stop cryptsvc`
6. Open My Computer, locate the folder C:\Windows\system32\catroot2
7. Rename "catroot2" to "oldcatroot2" (Windows will rebuild catroot2 when you restart)
8. Reboot
9. Go to Control Panel, Network Connections and Enable your connection again (we disabled this before, even though it may not have let you)

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove any third party firewall software, then do the update and reboot. If this solve the connectivity problem, then try reinstalling your security software. Many firewall products don't tolerate updates to components they monitor or interface with, and rather than reporting the issue, they just block all connections.

Answer (score 0):

You are not alone; this latest Microsoft Windows update has apparently zapped thousands of people's internet connections.

I have found that the easiest way to get you internet connection back is to take your computer back in time, just a day or two is sufficient, as long as it was before the update.   To accomplish this you go start, all programs, accessories, system tools, system restore.  Then pick a restore point before the update occurred, and like magic your computer will be just the way it was before that nasty update zapped your internet connection.  Then you will once again be able to connect to the internet with no problem, and your connection nightmare will be over!!

***  I'm sorry that didn't help you.  I didn't think about you not having a recent restore point.  The only reason I had such a recent one is because of recent hacking issues, so I now have a support contract with a PC care company, which was rather expensive by the way, and I have them scan and restore every few weeks.  It sounds like the other answers about firewalls are probably right, and I do wish you good luck getting through this frustrating situation -- darn computers!!