# Installing Windows Update kills my internet connection

Tags: windows, internet-connection, windows-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Update destroys my internet connection](https://superuser.com/questions/164742/windows-update-destroys-my-internet-connection)

After installing the latest version of Windows Update I still automatically connect but can't browse anything on the internet. When troubleshooting I get the error message "Windows can't communicate with the device or resource (primary DNS server)".

When I did system restore to a week ago the internet works again. However, when I then installed Windows Update the internet fails again with the same error message as before.

There is a previous thread referencing this problem: [Windows Update destroys my internet connection](https://superuser.com/questions/164742/windows-update-destroys-my-internet-connection). However, I don't see that as a permanent solution because I feel I cannot permanently defer installing the update in question.

Comment: Can you check the event logs and check if there are any errors? Does your internet connection need some specific proxy settings in IE or IP settings in network configuration? Some updates can reset such settings hence the problem.

Comment: @Luke, Maybe the question is a duplicate, but the solutions aren't.

Comment: @Ashwinkumar The question is the duplicate, and so far, 3 others agree. If it isn't a duplicate, then people will either edit the question to make sure it's not a duplicate, or it will be voted to be reopened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked it out: It was because of some horrible interaction between McAfee and the latest Windows Update.

See this for details: [Software Updates Causes Wireless Connectivity Issue Or Unable to Connect to Internet](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&cs=19&docid=576372&l=en&s=dhs)

> Due to a recent McAfee software update or Microsoft Windows update some computers are losing Internet connectivity. If you are now unable to access the Internet, use the steps below to restore connectivity.

Comment: Another reason to abandon horrible McAfee software, there are so many Free alternatives that are far superior to McAfee.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the only way to fix it was to disable auto update and do a system restore by going to Start, Accessories, System Tools, System Restore and selecting the time when it updated. Then I could use the internet again.

I contacted Dell. They told me it was McAfee's bad update that killed the internet, but it appears to be just a Windows update that's fatally flawed. They also told me it would be fixed within 24 hours. It's been a week and nothing.

Comment: Somehow my system gets auto updated and loses wifi connectivity. I have the same issue as well. Dell guys mentioned this is a McAfee issue and recommended me to have a system restore.